# Is it possible to grab related entries that have been attached to a certain field?

Tags: plugin-development

So,

I want to grab all entries that are related to an entry but with the following criteria:

1. Only from my section ($section)
2. Only the ones that have been added to a certain field ($fieldId)

I currently have this:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = $section;
$criteria->limit   = null;
$criteria->relatedTo = array(
    'targetElement' => $element,
);
$elements = craft()->elements->findElements($criteria);
return $elements;
```

But if I add two relationship fields to an entry, this will return ALL the associated entries from either field. I want to limit it to just the entries attached to the one field.

Is this possible? Does the question make sense? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to limit your relationships to a particular field, use this syntax:

```
$criteria->relatedTo = array(
    'targetElement' => $element,
    'field' => $field
);
```

I believe 'field' will take:

1) A single or array of $field instances

2) A single or array of field IDs or field handles.

Comment: That did! Appreciate it Brad.